# Strange bootstrap-datepicker behaviour with modal on Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) on a project and when the datetime picker shows on a modal it has a very strange behaviour, all the dates get swapped:

[image]

This only happens when in a modal, after scrolling the content and when using Firefox, in every other scenario its working normally.

To fully verify this bug i created a demo page: http://tuttipromo.blacklambs.net/Test.aspx

What can be the problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
                    {

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      language: 'pt',
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      autoclose: true,
      //appendTo: "div.modal",
      orientation: "top"
    });

  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditCampaign">
                Launch demo modal
            </button>





            <div id="modalEditCampaign" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
               
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                DatePicker
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-12 form-horizontal">

                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="tbEditCampaignStartDate" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Start</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                <input type="text" name="startDate" class="form-control input-normal datepicker" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="tbEditCampaignEndDate" class="col-sm-5 control-label">End</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input type="text" name="endDate" class="form-control input-normal datepicker" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: That's strange... I am assuming this is an issue with binding events for the datepicker when its input field is hidden (because the modal would be hidden initially). If possible, try calling `datepicker()` whenever the modal is displayed.

Comment: hi @nicolas i did what you said and called datepicker() when the modal is displayed, but the end result is the same. Any other suggestion?

Comment: If possible, please provide the code you're having issues with (bonus points for a JSFiddle or Stack Overflow code snippet).

Comment: Added code snippet to my question. I've also noticed that this only happens in Firefox, on Chrome and IE it works normally.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code! Oddly enough, I'm not seeing this issue on Firefox, Chrome, or Safari, and the datepicker seems to be in Portuguese.

Comment: yes, i'm using the portuguese version. i've added a test page can you check if its working correctly: [http://tuttipromo.blacklambs.net/Test.aspx](http://tuttipromo.blacklambs.net/Test.aspx) in my case it doesn't seem to work on Firefox.

Comment: That page also seem to work fine on Firefox for me. I'm using Firefox 36.0 on a OS X Yosemite.

Comment: @nicolas you need to scroll the modal in order to verify the issue. If you don't scroll the date picker works as expected. I added some dummy text for testing purposes. Can you verify?

Comment: I'm having a hard time scrolling the modal (since I have to make my window smaller than the datepicker component in order for the modal to be small enough for scrolling). I'm not seeing any extra dummy text in the modal. Did you forget to add it?

Comment: @nicolasmccurdy i added alot of dummy text to the page. but after updating FF to version 36.0.1 that strange datepicker behaviour doesn't happen no more or at least its not that severe: [screen shot](http://tinypic.com/r/30tt6d4/8) :)

Comment: That's odd, I assume you only selected one date originally? I'm starting to feel like this could be a Firefox bug. Did you notice any strange behavior in any other browser?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This issue was resolved with a FF update. All is good :D